# How to change background color for textAreaInput in r shiny?

Tags: shiny, textarea, background-color, shinydashboard

I used `textAreaInput()` in `dashboardHeader` to allow multiple lines in the header. But the background color of this text area is white and can't blend into the title panel there. I want to change the background color of this text area to either transparent or the same color as used in the `dashboardHeader`. I've tried something like below. But it does not work. Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyApp(server = function(input, output) {}, ui = 

dashboardPage(skin = "blue",

dashboardHeader(
    title = textAreaInput(inputId = 'header',label = NULL, 
                          width = 250, height = 100,
                          value = "This is a very very very very very loooooong title"
                      ),
    titleWidth = 260
),

dashboardSidebar(
    width = 260,     
    sidebarMenu(
       menuItem("About", tabName = "about", icon = icon("circle")),
       menuItem("References", tabName = "ref", icon = icon("book"))
     )
),

dashboardBody(

    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
           .textArea {
              background-color: #0000ff;
              border: none;
            }
     '))),

    tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = 'about'),
        tabItem(tabName = 'ref')
    )
)
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have two choises

first one if you want to change the backgrondcolor for every textArea. I need to remove the dot before textArea because it is a tag not a class the dots before tells the identifier to look for a class. then you need to add !important after the color like this.

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
   textArea {
     background-color: #0000ff !important;
     border: none;
   }')))
```

the second is if you only want to change the background color for this specific textArea is better to use the id `#header` and in this case you don't need the `!important`

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
  #header{
    background-color: #0000ff !important;
    border: none;
    }')))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply! Both ways worked perfectly! I also tried `background: transparent` within `textArea` or `#header` and it worked too. It is easier that I don't need to know the exact hex code used for the default color there. But I would need to change the text color to make it better visible then.